# How to open multiple chrome tabs using webbrowser.open in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to execute multiple lines of code so that each line opens 1 URL in its own tab. So for 5 lines of code, I want 5 different chrome tabs to open. However, when I run my code, only the first line executes. In order to fully execute the block, I have to run the code a second time. I want all 5 to open on the first try.

I have tried different indentations and included an if statement for the first URL, but neither has seemed to help.

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(URL1)
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new_tab(URL2)    
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new_tab(URL3)
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new_tab(URL4)
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new_tab(URL5)
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new_tab(URL6)
```

I expect all 5 of these to open on the first run. Only the first URL opens on the first run. I have to run the code again for the other URL's to open.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this will work only if there's a tab open in chrome before executing the script.

You can try this instead:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open(URL)
```

This will open the URL with default browser so make sure you have set chrome as default in your case.